# Querying lines that meet in endpoints to show result in clockwise order?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I have some polylines - roads. They meet in an intersection like on the picture:

[image]

I want to find out which roads meets `Road A` - endpoint to endpoint - and i want to know the clockwise order of the result. Thus, the example in the picture should return in the order:

```
{ROAD C, ROAD D, ROAD B}
```

Using `IFeatureClass.Search()` with a `ISpatialFilter` only returns the features ordered by OBJECTID (The road names illustrate the order og OBJECTID).

Do I have to do the math myself, or is there some smart esri woodoo that I can do?

Answer (score 2):

As you have discovered the order of polylines is dictated by the row order returned in the cursor so you will have to do some post processing. This is how I would do it:

1. For each polyline identify which end is intersecting road A (i.e. from or to end)
2. Cast polyline into IPointcollection and depending on the orientation get the next vertex along its length.
3. You now have 2 points, convert these into an ILine object
4. Use this new ILine object in the [IConstructAngle.ConstructLine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000000qr000000) method, note this uses radians, at which point my brain blows up as I never understand radians :)
5. Store the angles, object ID in a dictionary, sort and report as required

Answer (score 0):

You have completed the first step. You have to process these features (those you retreive in the initial spatial query) further to locate a common end node. Find the end-node of the source line then compare ot to each end node of each line in your cursor using IPoint:x,y,z. A simple loop will do.